# error "/modules: Permission denied" after changing the permissions while rebuilding opencv-3.1.0 with extra modules opencv_contrib?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

I'm using Opencv 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

after downloading opencv_contrib then moving the folder to /home/MY_NAME/opencv-3.1.0/build then type in terminal cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib/modules opencv_source_directory

I had this error "bash: /modules: Permission denied" then I've changed the permission to both opencv_contrib/modules & build/modules with chmod 777 FileName

then logout to know if anything changes

Unfortunately, I still have this error "bash: /modules: Permission denied" please, could you tell me what's the problem.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the opencv_contrib folder in /home/MY_NAME/opencv_contrib, then, try with absolute path:

cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/MY_NAME/opencv_contrib/modules ..

Comment: Still not working for me